# Generating report or table for buffer zone using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, intersection

I have a polygon feature class.

I create a buffer for this feature with a distance being 2 km.

Now the buffer output intersect with features of the original polygon.

So say for instance from the orginal polygon id 1 it creates a buffer polygon with id 1a.

Now I want a report or table of all the features the 1a intersects with the original polygon.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel, as you suggested, could be used, but I would use [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) (which outputs to PDF) when using ArcPy for map automation, or the included Report Writer (**View** | **Reports** > **Create Report**) when doing it from the ArcMap GUI.